# Sonarqube: list of the projects that are not comply with a rule

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-api

I'm using SonarQube 8.9 LTS and I need to find all the projects in my SonarQube instance that do not comply with the rule Track uses of 'NOSONAR' comments using the SonarQube REST API.

I've tried this request:

http://<mysonar_url>/api/issues/search?resolved=false&rules=java%3ANoSonar&facets=projects

It works, but it finds 92,416 violations as you can see

[image]

Using pagination, it's quite difficult to extract the list of projects that do not comply with the rule.

Is there a way to extract this project list using a SonarQube REST API request?

Thank you in advance!"